# Difficulty removing rows

Tags: r

one of the columns in my data frame -z- contains weekdays. I would like to remove rows that have "Sunday" and "Saturday" as factor.
I used without success `r<-z[-c(z$x=="Sunday" & z$x=="Saturday", ]` and 
`r<-subset(z, x!=="Sunday" & x!=="Saturday")`. `x` is the name of the column.

Could you please help figure it out? Thanks. The data:

```
y   x
1   1   Monday
2   2   Monday
3   3   Monday
4   4   Monday
5   5   Monday
6   6   Monday
7   7   Monday
8   8   Friday
9   9   Friday
10  10  Friday
11  11  Friday
12  12  Sunday
13  13  Sunday
14  14  Sunday
15  15  Sunday
16  16  Saturday
17  17  Saturday
18  18  Saturday
19  19  Saturday
20  20  Saturday
```

UPDATE:
I accepted the answer as it worked with the df I provided. When I try to apply it to the df I have it does not do anything.  I use 
`flexW<-subset(flex, Day!="Sunday" & Day!="Saturday")`

The selected variable from the data frame:

> str(flex)
>   'data.frame':   177237 obs. of  14 variables:
>    ....
>    $ Day            : Factor w/ 7 levels " Friday"," Monday",..: 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 ...

Comment: Please give a reproducible example using a data that's accessible to everyone-e.g. `mtcars` data in R. I'll have a go and get back to you.

Comment: Your code would be fine **but** you need to understand that this is being tested per row/observation. There's no way that x for a row can be both "Sunday" and "Saturday". What you mean to test is whether it's Sunday or Saturday. The (first couple) answers below obscure this fact because `x == "Sunday" | x == "Saturday"` can be more concisely written as `x %in% c("Saturday","Sunday")`. Also, minor thing: the `-` to negate only works if you're evaluating row numbers. For logical, you'll want `!`

Comment: And, in your second try, `!==` isn't valid R, `!=` is what you want.

Comment: Thanks for your explanations. The answer below worked well and I can understand now better why.

Comment: Your post is likely to get less attention now that your original question has been answered. You might consider starting a new question with "reproducible" data http://stackoverflow.com/a/28481250/1191259

Comment: Thanks, I will wait for a while and if nothing comes up will ask a new question.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Filtering a data frame in R](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1686569/filtering-a-data-frame-in-r)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

following your example, try this:

```
subset(z, x!="Sunday" & x!="Saturday")
```

Comment: I accepted the answer as it worked with the df I provided. When I try to apply it to the df I have it does not do anything.

Comment: Please see the update to the question. It does not give any error, but apparently saves the same data frame.

Comment: It definitely works when I run it on R-are you sure you're saving it as a different object?

Comment: try running this and tell me what it gives you `str(flexW)`.

Comment: John, I just created a reproducible dataset. Tried on it with the same result. I will follow the advice to ask a new question as it is easier for me to  insert all the data. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Just a base R solution:

```
dat[!dat$x %in% c("Sunday", "Saturday"), ]
    y      x
1   1 Monday
2   2 Monday
3   3 Monday
4   4 Monday
5   5 Monday
6   6 Monday
7   7 Monday
8   8 Friday
9   9 Friday
10 10 Friday
11 11 Friday
```

or one with `dplyr`, almost the same syntax.

```
dat %>% filter(!x %in% c("Sunday", "Saturday"))
```

Comment: this is easier to read than big conditional statements jammed in a one liner

Comment: @AaronKatch Personally, I find `!x` very misleading/hard to read. Needs more parens and/or better spacing to show what is being negated: `!( x %in% c("a","b") )`

Comment: @Frank your code style is better, thank you for this hint.

Answer (score 2):

```
> x[x$X != 'Saturday' & x$X!= 'Sunday',]
    y  x      X
1   1  1 Monday
2   2  2 Monday
3   3  3 Monday
4   4  4 Monday
5   5  5 Monday
6   6  6 Monday
7   7  7 Monday
8   8  8 Friday
9   9  9 Friday
10 10 10 Friday
11 11 11 Friday
```

Answer (score 1):

From your error output, you have  `" Friday"," Monday"` as inputs. The leading spaces are being stripped as people here try and reproduce, you need to use `dput(flex)` rather than paste so things like this don't happen.

I guess your saturday and sunday columns are the same, so try:

```
 z[!(z$x %in% c(" Saturday", " Sunday")), ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this could work for you:

```
 z[!z$x %in% c("Saturday", "Sunday"), ]
```