# Is the r function `match()` directionally dependent?

Tags: r, match, subset, matching

I am using the binary operator `%in%` to subset a dataframe (I got the idea from another stackoverflow [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1686569/filtering-a-data-frame-in-r)), but when I double check the result by switching the arguments, I get different answers. I've read the R documentation on the `match()` function, and it seems like neither `match()` nor `%in%` should be directionally dependent. I really need to understand exactly what is happening to be confident in my results. Could anybody provide some insight?

```
> filtered_ordGeneNames_proteinIDs <- ordGeneNames_ProteinIDs[ordGeneNames_ProteinIDs$V4 %in% ordDEGs$X, ];
> filtered2_ordGeneNames_proteinIDs <- ordDEGs[ordDEGs$X %in% ordGeneNames_ProteinIDs$V4, ];
> nrow(filtered_ordGeneNames_proteinIDs)
[1] 5767
> nrow(filtered2_ordGeneNames_proteinIDs)
[1] 5746
```

Comment: Did you take a look at `help("match")`?

Comment: Perhaps you're looking for `intersect()`?

Comment: Where is the hint in the doc that let you think that `neither match() nor %in% should be directionally dependent`?

Comment: Very simple. Yes, yes it is. First argument to`%in%` is the table you have available and on the righthand side, you supply the values you would like to check if they appear in that very same table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course you have different results:

```
ordGeneNames_ProteinIDs$V4 %in% ordDEGs$X
```

tells you which element of `ordGeneNames_ProteinIDs$V4` that is also in `ordDEGs$X`

where :

```
ordDEGs %in% $XordGeneNames_ProteinIDs$V4
```

tells you which element of `ordDEGs$X` that is also in `ordGeneNames_ProteinIDs$V4`

compare

```
c(1,2,3,4) %in% c(1,2,1, 2)
[1]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
```

to

```
c(1,2,1, 2) %in% c(1,2,3,4)
[1] TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE
```

Comment: Many thanks. Implicit assumptions got me on this one. Gene names are supposed to be unique. There shouldn't have been any duplicates in the `ordGeneNames_ProteinIDs` dataframe, but a quick check with `duplicated()` told me that there definitely were.