# How to remove rows of data in .csv files in R?

Tags: r

Basically I have a .csv file that has a column of data where I only want the rows that have that given column with a certain value. Is there a way to do this?

`

Comment: `df = df[df$RelevantColumn == RelevantValue,]`

Comment: or `subset(df, RelevantColumn == RelevantValue)`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Filtering a data.frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1686569/filtering-a-data-frame)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
df <- data.frame(x=c(1,3,3,4),
                 y=c(1,2,3,4))

df[df$x==3,]
```

Output:

```
  x y
2 3 2
3 3 3
```