# How to filtering "character" like Excel in R

Tags: r, filtering

・This is the table , name: x

```
==================================================================
 # A tibble: 6 x 10
     ID   blood  age  hair_color name height weight distance expiry
    <dbl> <chr> <dbl>    <chr>  <chr>  <dbl>  <dbl>    <dbl>  <dbl>
1     1     P    60     yellow  john    999    128      110    120
2     2     N    52      black   tom    999    180      156    160
3     3     P   100      white   tom    999    190      140    999
4     4     N    84     yellow   tom    112    136      126    122
5     5     P    56      brown   tom     64    230      150    130
6     6     P   105      green   dan    999    142      150    999
===================================================================

.Expected Image:
 ===================================================================
      ID   blood age  hair_color     name height weight distance expiry
    <dbl> <chr> <dbl>     <chr>     <chr>  <dbl>  <dbl>    <dbl>  <dbl>
1     1     P    60       yellow    john    999    128      110    120
2     4     N    84       yellow    tom     112    136      126    122
===================================================================
```

.Backgound:Beginner

Moverover, how to

1.filtering data with "contain" function?
 -like: extract data in column:hair_color ,contain "ye"

2.filtering data with multi conditions?
 -like: in column:hair_color ,contain "ye"
        and
        in column:name ,start with "to"

Simply imaging how to do something exactly like working in Excel,
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Filtering a data.frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1686569/filtering-a-data-frame)

Comment: Thank you very much . It works with using dplyr package --filter function.       But i still unable to mix filter function with contain command.

Comment: From the help, `contains` and related functions *"allow you to select variables based on their names"*. The key part is "select variables", not "filter rows". In a `data.frame`, a variable is a column. Use `grepl`, perhaps as `dplyr::filter(x, grepl("ye", hair_color))`. It also works just fine outside of `dplyr`, ala `x[grepl("ye", x$hair_color),]` or by using `subset`, as in KarstenW's answer (though `subset` warns against programmatic use).

Answer (score 0):

In interactive mode, you could use `subset`:

1)

```
subset(x, grepl("ye", hair_color, fixed=TRUE))
```

2)

```
subset(x, grepl("ye", hair_color, fixed=TRUE) & grepl("^to", name))
```

In the second example the caret `^` means "start with" in regular expressions.

So in short, the simple text filtering functions known from excel can be achieved and much extended with `grepl`. A short course on regular expressions helps to unleash its real power.

Comment: Thankyou very much! I feel like find back my hands and legs from Excel.

Comment: You're welcome! Feel free to upvote or accept the answer if it is helpful to you.