# count up number of rows that have > 0 count in R data frame

Tags: r

I have a dataframe `df`. It looks like:

```
xSample    a b  c
x          2 0  2
x1         3 0  0
x2         4 0  2
```

I have this piece of code: 
`new_df <- as.data.frame(sapply(df[,-1], function(x) sum(as.numeric(x) > 0)))`

I want to go through each column of `df` and count the number of samples and put that into `new_df`, but only if there are > 0 counts per sample A, B, or C... The `new_df` **should** look like this:

```
       NonZeroCounts
a         3 
c         2
```

The `b` row is not kept because it has 0 counts in every row.

After running my function mentioned above on my `df`, the output is:

```
xSample     NonZeroCounts
a          3 
b          0 
c          2
```

Comment: You can just remove that row where `NonZeroCounts == 0`. [Filter data.frame rows by a logical condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1686569/filter-data-frame-rows-by-a-logical-condition) should help you with that.

Comment: ...or you could contain the sum statement in an ifelse statement and return NULL if the sum is equal to Zero....it would remove that row.

Comment: `data.frame(NonZeroCounts = sapply(df1[-1], function(x) sum(x>0))[colSums(df1[-1]) > 0])`

Comment: @d.b This is great, thank you. If you add this as an answer, I can accept.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, use `sapply` to go through the relevant columns and obtain the number of non-zero values. Then, use `colSums` to subset only those values that are greater than `0`

```
data.frame(NonZeroCounts = sapply(df1[-1], function(x)
    sum(x>0))[colSums(df1[-1]) > 0])
#  NonZeroCounts
#a             3
#c             2
```

**DATA**

```
df1 = structure(list(xSample = c("x", "x1", "x2"), a = 2:4, b = c(0L, 
0L, 0L), c = c(2L, 0L, 2L)), .Names = c("xSample", "a", "b", 
"c"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))
```

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, including an explanation really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion

Comment: is it possible to do something similar with data that contains NA?

Answer (score 1):

Another way of doing this:

```
## Your data
df <- data.frame(a = c(2, 3, 4), b = c(0, 0, 0), c = c(2, 0, 2))

data.frame(NonZeroCounts=colSums(df!=0)[colSums(df!=0)!=0])

#    NonZeroCounts
#a          3
#c          2
```