# Filter data frame

Tags: r

I have a big data frame called df(500k rows & 50 columns). I need to filter this data frame based in two conditions at the same time (i.e: I need to remove the rows that have values grater than 0.6 and values less than 0.1 for all columns at the same time)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Filter data.frame rows by a logical condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1686569/filter-data-frame-rows-by-a-logical-condition)

Comment: This would be a much better question with a small example input with desired output.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I understood what you meant by "for all columns at the same time" but if you meant remove rows that have a value in any column that is greater than 0.6 or smaller than 0.1 then a solution

```
keep <- apply(df,1, function(x){
  all(x < 0.6 & x> 0.1)
})

filtered_df <- df[keep,]
```

Answer (score 0):

If we need to `filter` for all columns, use `filter_all` with `all_vars`

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
      filter_all(all_vars(!(. > 0.6 & . <  0.1)))
```