# Unable to filter sampled dataframe - R

Tags: r, dataframe, filter, dplyr

I have dataframe that is a result of

```
new_df <- dat %>% group_by(ID) %>% sample_frac(0.25,replace = FALSE)
```

data frame looks like this:

```
Ad.ID    ID
1234     deroy
2345     deroy
4567     deroy
34567    mrroy
13467    mrroy
00024    ronde
32243    ronde
```

trying to filter out rows specific to certian IDs i.e. for deroy or mrroy but unable to.

```
exp <- new_df[new_df$ID %in%"deroy",]
```

using grepl was able to do it for one ID, but if I wanted to do it for two or three it doesn't work.

Please do not mark as duplicate because I Have tried all suggestions from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1686569/filter-data-frame-rows-by-a-logical-condition) and few other places.

I maybe missing out some basics. Any help is appreciated.

> Adding dput:

```
structure(list(Ad.ID = c(75856740L, 75899591L, 75904815L, 75911256L, 
75911261L, 75911267L, 75911277L, 75911277L, 75911291L, 75911302L, 
75905790L, 75905815L, 75905818L, 75910661L, 75914385L, 75902382L, 
75902383L, 75902384L, 75902386L, 75902391L), ID = c("deroy                         
", 
"deroy                         ", "deroy                         ", 
"deroy                         ", "deroy                         ", 
"deroy                         ", "deroy                         ", 
"deroy                         ", "deroy                         ", 
"deroy                         ", "deroy                         ", 
"deroy                         ", "deroy                         ", 
"deroy                         ", "jishuroy                      ", 
"jishuroy                      ", "jishuroy                      ", 
"jishuroy                      ", "jishuroy                      ", 
"jishuroy                      ")), .Names = c("Ad.ID", "ID"), row.names = 
c(1L, 
2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 16L, 
17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: What do you mean by unable to? Do you get an error? Because If I test your `new_df[new_df$ID %in%"deroy",]` code it returns the rows with "deroy"

Comment: @phiver after running the code my console gives                                                  # A tibble: 0 x 2
# Groups:   ID [0]
# ... with 2 variables: Ad.ID <int>, ID <chr>

Comment: Since you are using dplyr see what happens if you do `new_df %>% filter(ID == "deroy")`.

Comment: @phiver still same result

Comment: All options on your example data work as they should. I think you have to check spelling mistakes / trailing spaces etc in your data. Or if you add the outcome of  `dput(head(dat, 20))` to your question. Because now I can't see what the issue is.

Comment: Thanks @phiver added dput as suggested though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your data, your ID column is 30 long. You have a lot of empty spaces behind every word. Before you continue, first clean that up.

```
nchar(new_df$ID[1])
30
```

Using dplyr:

```
new_df %>% 
  mutate(ID = gsub(" ", "", ID)) %>%
  filter(ID == "jishuroy")

     Ad.ID       ID
1 75914385 jishuroy
2 75902382 jishuroy
3 75902383 jishuroy
4 75902384 jishuroy
5 75902386 jishuroy
6 75902391 jishuroy
```

Using base R:

```
new_df$ID <- gsub(" ", "", new_df$ID)
new_df[new_df$ID == "jishuroy", ]
      Ad.ID       ID
16 75914385 jishuroy
17 75902382 jishuroy
18 75902383 jishuroy
19 75902384 jishuroy
20 75902386 jishuroy
21 75902391 jishuroy
```

Comment: Thanks @phiver mutate did not work, but base R did. Thank you again!!

Answer (score 0):

try :

```
df1 = new_df %>% filter(id == 'deroy')
df2 = new_df %>% filter(id == 'mrroy')
df3 = new_df %>% filter(id %in% c('mrroy', 'deroy'))
```

Comment: Thank you!. Still same result. The output is 0

Answer (score 0):

One easy option would be to use `trimws` to remove the leading/lagging spaces in the "ID" column and then use `filter`

```
library(dplyr)
new_df %>%
       filter(trimws(ID) == "jishuroy")
```

and for multiple IDs, use the `%in%` as in the OP's post