# Subsetting data in R based on a test

Tags: r, dplyr

I would like to subset a dataframe based on a test performed. For instance, I ran the test
   `CheckUnsystematic(dat = long, deltaq = 0.025, bounce = 0.1, reversals = 0, ncons0 = 2)`

It gave me this:

```
    > CheckUnsystematic(dat = long, deltaq = 0.025, bounce = 0.1, reversals = 0, ncons0 = 2)
    > CheckUnsystematic(dat = long, deltaq = 0.025, bounce = 0.1, reversals = 0, ncons0 = 2)
     id TotalPass DeltaQ DeltaQPass Bounce BouncePass Reversals ReversalsPass NumPosValues
1     2         3 0.9089       Pass 0.0000       Pass         0          Pass           15
2     3         3 0.6977       Pass 0.0000       Pass         0          Pass           16
3     4         2 0.0000       Fail 0.0000       Pass         0          Pass           18
4     5         3 0.2107       Pass 0.0000       Pass         0          Pass           18
5     6         3 0.2346       Pass 0.0000       Pass         0          Pass           18
6     7         3 0.9089       Pass 0.0000       Pass         0          Pass           16
7     8         3 0.9622       Pass 0.0000       Pass         0          Pass           15
8     9         3 0.8620       Pass 0.0000       Pass         0          Pass           11
9    10         3 0.9089       Pass 0.0000       Pass         0          Pass           12
10   11         3 0.9089       Pass 0.0000       Pass         0          Pass           11
```

I want to keep only the observations that have a "3" in "TotalPass".

I tried this:
   `CleanAPT <- long[ which(long$TotalPass==3),]`

Comment: Looks fine, good job. (Not sure how `CheckUnsystematic()` is relevant... is that how you decided on `3`? Is it related to what you need help with? What *do* you need help with? Your code looks fine.)

Comment: I apologize. I should've added that the new dataset, "CleanAPT", shows 0 obs of 3 variables. It isn't registering the = 3 part. The dataset doesn't originally have a TotalPass column and doesnt show one after the test either. How do I get the test to either make a DF or use that to subset my data to only that occurrence?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Filter data.frame rows by a logical condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1686569/filter-data-frame-rows-by-a-logical-condition)

Comment: It seems thay maybe you are showing the output of `CheckUnsystematic()`, not the data frame you are trying to subset. Could you show what `long` looks like? Does it have a column named `TotalPass`? Maybe also include the package information for where `CheckUnsystematic` comes from, I'm not familiar...

Comment: This is correct! That is exactly what I am doing. Long looks like this: `## view the first 20 rows
> knitr::kable(long[1:20, ])


| id|     x|  y|
|--:|-----:|--:|
|  1|  0.00| NA|
|  1|  0.25| NA|
|  1|  0.50| NA|
|  1|  1.00| NA|
|  1|  1.50| NA|
|  1|  2.00| NA|
|  1|  2.50| NA|
|  1|  3.00| NA|
|  1|  4.00| NA|
|  1|  5.00| NA|
|  1|  6.00| NA|
|  1|  7.00| NA|
|  1|  8.00| NA|
|  1|  9.00| NA|
|  1| 10.00| NA|
|  1| 12.00| NA|
|  1| 15.00| NA|
|  1| 20.00| NA|
|  2|  0.00| 10|
|  2|  0.25| 10|`

Comment: It is from the package beezdemand for running behavioral economic tasks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you did tag this as a `dplyr` question, let's use it:

```
library(dplyr)

check_df <- CheckUnsystematic(dat = long, deltaq = 0.025, 
                              bounce = 0.1, reversals = 0, ncons0 = 2)

CleanAPT <- check_df %>%
  filter(TotalPass == 3)
```

The reason the `CleanAPT <- long[ which(long$TotalPass==3),]` is not working is because you are calling on the `long` dataframe (which is unmodified from the `CheckUnsystematic` function).  In the above, I save the function results to `check_df`.  So, `CleanAPT <- check_df[which(check_df$TotalPass==3),]` should work.

Merging back with the original data (difficult to say exactly how to do this since column names of `long` - so assuming `id` is present and unique), can be done with a `semi_join` from `dplyr`:

```
long_filtered <- long %>%
  mutate(id = as.character(id)) %>%
  semi_join(CleanAPT %>%
              mutate(id = as.character(id)),
            by = "id")
```

Comment: This works! However, I want the data to be the data before the test. Would the best way to do this to match and merge the id's from the CleanAPT and long df's?

Comment: I think this is really close now, but I am getting the error `Error in semi_join_impl(x, y, by$x, by$y, check_na_matches(na_matches)) : 
  Can't join on 'id' x 'id' because of incompatible types (integer / character)`

Comment: Made changes, although you may need to modify depending on what variables are available in `long`

Comment: These are the only ones in long 
`## view the first 20 rows > knitr::kable(long[1:20, ]) | id| x| y| |--:|-----:|--:| | 1| 0.00| NA| | 1| 0.25| NA| | 1| 0.50| NA| | 1| 1.00| NA| | 1| 1.50| NA| | 1| 2.00| NA| | 1| 2.50| NA| | 1| 3.00| NA| | 1| 4.00| NA| | 1| 5.00| NA| | 1| 6.00| NA| | 1| 7.00| NA| | 1| 8.00| NA| | 1| 9.00| NA| | 1| 10.00| NA| | 1| 12.00| NA| | 1| 15.00| NA| | 1| 20.00| NA| | 2| 0.00| 10| | 2| 0.25| 10| `

However, the 'long' df isn't changing obs. after the `semi_join`.

Comment: well in your example, the `id == 4` should be filtered out.  `long` should stay the same, but `long_filtered` should be the output you're looking for.  if you want, change `long_filtered <- long %>% ...` to `long <- long %>% ...`

Comment: Right! I am sorry that I am being confusing. I am not even getting a long_filtered df

Comment: Yessir. 

`check_df <- CheckUnsystematic(dat = long, deltaq = 0.025, bounce = 0.1, reversals = 0, ncons0 = 2)
Error: unexpected symbol in:
"                     by = "id")
check_df"
> 
> CleanAPT <- check_df %>%
+   filter(TotalPass == 3)
> 
> long_filtered <- long %>%
+   mutate(id = as.numeric(id)) %>%
+   semi_join(CleanAPT %>%
+               mutate(id = as.numeric(id),
+                      by = "id")`

Comment: whoops! Forgot a `)`.  Guess I shouldn't be coding without opening up R :)

Comment: I thought this much but I don't have the experience to correct anyone. Thank you so much! You have helped tremendously.

Answer (score 0):

Try this with your long dataset.

```
CleanAPT <- subset(long, TotalPass == 3)

CheckUnsystematic(dat = CleanAPT, deltaq = 0.025, bounce = 0.1, reversals = 0, ncons0 = 2)
```

Comment: I thought it was outputting your data as a data frame for the subset? If not, after you run CheckUnsystematic(), fortify the results using the package ggfortify() like so: fortify("what you named the CheckUnsystematic() output"). After the data frame is created then subset() the data.