# Correct syntax to filter or select rows from a data frame using a function

Tags: r, select, filter, tidyverse

I am trying to filter or subset a data frame so it only includes rows where the contents of a column start with a certain letter.

I have tried to use `subset` and `filter` and `select` (including `starts_with` from `dplyr`) but I can't seem to find the right syntax to achieve what I need. All the examples I have found demonstrate filtering according to a value e.g. `x > 1` or similar, rather than via a function.
I have managed only to create a staggering variety of different error messages.

refs:
https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/dplyr/versions/0.7.8/topics/select
https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/dplyr/versions/0.7.8/topics/filter_all
https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/tidyselect/versions/0.1.1/topics/select_helpers
https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.5.1/topics/startsWith
[Filter data.frame rows by a logical condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1686569/filter-data-frame-rows-by-a-logical-condition)

```
library(tidyverse)
a <- c("A1435","A6732","A8841","B7623","B7714","B3154")
b <- c("place 1", "place 2", "place 3", "place 4", "place 5", "place 6")
test_frame <- data.frame(a,b)
```

Here are some of the things I've tried:

```
subset <- subset(test_frame, subset = startsWith(test_frame$a, "A"))
## Error in startsWith(test_frame$a, "A") : non-character object(s)
```

```
subset <- subset(test_frame, subset = startsWith(test_frame[,1], "A") == 1)
## Error in startsWith(test_frame[, 1], "A") : non-character object(s)
```

```
subset <- test_frame %>% dplyr::select(test_frame, starts_with("A", ignore.case = TRUE, vars = a))
## Error: `test_frame` must evaluate to column positions or names, not a list
```

```
subset <- dplyr::select(test_frame, starts_with("A", ignore.case = TRUE, vars = a))
## Error in inds_combine(.vars, ind_list) : Position must be between 0 and n
```

```
subset <- test_frame %>% dplyr::filter_if(test_frame$a, ~ starts_with("A"))
## Error: Can't convert a `factor` object to function
```

```
subset <- vars_select(test_frame, starts_with("A"))
## Error: `vars` must be a character vector
```

```
subset <- dplyr::filter(test_frame, dplyr::starts_with("A"), all_vars(. == a))
## Error: No tidyselect variables were registered
```

```
subset <- test_frame$a %>% grep("^A", .)
## [1] 1 2 3
```

This last try at least doesn't give me an error - but nor does it help me make a subset of the data frame. Can I combine this grep with one of the above functions to get my result maybe?

I had assumed this task would be quite easy, but I have spent a whole day on it without success. So, what am I missing?

*** EDIT: Amazing - several really helpful respoinses within minutes of posting. Thank you everyone, thank you Stack Overflow! ***

Comment: when creating the dataframe, use `setStringsAsFactors = TRUE`

Comment: In base R, `test_frame <- data.frame(a,b,stringsAsFactors=FALSE); subset(test_frame, startsWith(a, "A"))` -- you don't need 'verse syntax.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `grepl`

```
 test_frame[grepl("^A", test_frame$a), ]
      a       b
1 A1435 place 1
2 A6732 place 2
3 A8841 place 3
```

Answer (score 4):

We can use `select_if` to select the columns based on a condition

```
test_frame %>% 
    select_if( ~ any(str_detect(.x, "A")))
```

---

Or for `filter`ing the rows

```
test_frame %>% 
     filter_all(any_vars(str_detect(., "A")))
#      a       b
#1 A1435 place 1
#2 A6732 place 2
#3 A8841 place 3
```

Or using a subset of columns

```
test_frame %>%
     filter_at(vars(starts_with("a")), any_vars(str_detect(., "A")))
```

---

Or using `base R`

```
i1 <- Reduce(`|`, lapply(test_frame[startsWith(names(test_frame), "a")],
            grepl, pattern ="^A"))
test_frame[i1,]
```

Answer (score 2):

A less efficient solution added for variety:

```
 test_frame[startsWith(as.character(test_frame$a),"A"),]


   #    a       b
   # 1 A1435 place 1
   # 2 A6732 place 2
   # 3 A8841 place 3
```