# How to check the validity of a value on a column based on a knowlege list

Tags: r

I am cleaning a dataset using R with a country abbreviation code attribute. I want to check the validity of each value in that column by matching up with a list of county abbreviation. How can I do this with R? I am a beginner to R.

Following is a sample data set

[image]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you have a list of county abbreviation to match it up with? Do you want to remove the rows which do not match?

Comment: So, one of the attributes is Country.Code and you want to validate the values of that attribute, for every ID? If yes, do you want them to match with which values?

Comment: `df$County.Code %in% list_of_county_abbreviation`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Filter data.frame rows by a logical condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1686569/filter-data-frame-rows-by-a-logical-condition)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `anti_join()` from `dplyr` to filter your dataset for values that are not in another dataset, you can do the following:

```r
library(tibble) # for tibble (a data_frame)
library(dplyr)  # for anti_join

# Create some data
df <- tibble(
  country = c("ABC", "DEF", "GHI", "WRONG"),
  other_data = rnorm(4)
)

df
#> # A tibble: 4 x 2
#>   country other_data
#>   <chr>        <dbl>
#> 1 ABC         -0.277
#> 2 DEF          1.09 
#> 3 GHI         -0.184
#> 4 WRONG       -0.150

countries <- tibble(
  country = c("ABC", "DEF", "GHI", "JKL", "MNO"),
  name = c("some", "long", "names", "or", "so")
)
countries
#> # A tibble: 5 x 2
#>   country name 
#>   <chr>   <chr>
#> 1 ABC     some 
#> 2 DEF     long 
#> 3 GHI     names
#> 4 JKL     or   
#> 5 MNO     so

# get only the countries that are NOT in countries
anti_join(df, countries, by = "country")
#> # A tibble: 1 x 2
#>   country other_data
#>   <chr>        <dbl>
#> 1 WRONG       -0.150
```

<sup>Created on 2019-05-10 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>