# problem finding rows in a dataset as a function of column value

Tags: r

I'm new to R. I am trying to select all rows from a dataset where column x = y. Where y is an integer.

My code:

```
data_sub <- data_full[data_full$x == y,]
```

I am encountering a strange problem where the argument is returning the rows I asked for plus all rows in `data_full` where `x = NA`.

Has anyone encountered this before / could you explain it to me?

Comment: you need to filter the `NA`s, do `df[df$x == y & !is.na(df$x),]` Or `na.omit(df[df$x == y, ])` Or `df[df$x == y & complete.cases(df), ]`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `dplyr` package.

```
library(dplyr)
data_sub <- data_full %>% 
  dplyr::filter(x == y)
```

Or several other options.

[Filter data.frame rows by a logical condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1686569/filter-data-frame-rows-by-a-logical-condition)