# Using value in Specific Row to Filter the Columns in R

Tags: r, select, row

I have to subset a dataframe based on a specific value of a row. This means that if the row containing values greater than 10 must be used as criteria to extract all the column that satisfy the condition in that row.

Here is my data sample.

```
structure(list(`Copper ores and concentrates; copper mattes, cemen` = c(200.53, 
274.84, 1.37, 376.686907694609), `Fabrics, woven, of man-made fabrics` = c(4093.12, 
1184.47, 0.29, 342.762777758776), Copper = c(44.76, 91.45, 2.04, 
186.843219392315), Zinc = c(80.14, 110.73, 1.38, 152.996417519341
), `Waste, parings and scrap, of plastics` = c(590.3, 286.3, 
0.49, 138.857682534305), `Fixed vegetable fats & oils, crude, refined, fract.` = c(864.14, 
344.63, 0.4, 137.44281817761), `Sulphur and unroasted iron pyrites` = c(23.99, 
55.11, 2.3, 126.599087119633), `Radio-actives and associated materials` = c(48.59, 
76.67, 1.58, 120.977338958633), `Rails & railway track construction mat., iron, steel` = c(464.66, 
214.76, 0.46, 99.259367279301), `Iron ore and concentrates` = c(46.91, 
67.8, 1.45, 97.9927520784481), `Crude vegetable materials, n.e.s.` = c(164.46, 
123.26, 0.75, 92.3812939316551), `Other plastics, in primary forms` = c(187.76, 
124.21, 0.66, 82.169386983383), `Crude animal materials, n.e.s.` = c(43.08, 
56.52, 1.31, 74.1529805013928), `Pig iron & spiegeleisen, sponge iron, powder & granu` = c(17.17, 
33.03, 1.92, 63.5399475829936), `Ores and concentrates of base metals, n.e.s.` = c(15.7, 
27.6, 1.76, 48.5197452229299), `Furskins, tanned or dressed, excluding those of 8483` = c(178.49, 
75.12, 0.42, 31.6152972155303), `Metalworking machinery (excludingmachine-tools) & parts` = c(179.18, 
71.69, 0.4, 28.6832018082375)), row.names = c("SD", "Mean", "INTENSITY", 
"INTENSITY2"), class = "data.frame")
```

I want that the dataframe must limit itself to values greater than 10 in the row named `INTENSITY2`.

I tried this  `tf4[, tf4[,"INTENSITY2" > 10, ]]` but it does not work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Filter data.frame rows by a logical condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1686569/filter-data-frame-rows-by-a-logical-condition)

Comment: this is different, just checked the page.

Comment: Try it: `df[, df["INTENSITY2", ] > 10, FALSE]`. The only difference with your code is in filtering: you made a typo and filtering by column values, not by row ones.

Comment: It gives error as `Error in `[.data.frame`(tf4, , tf4["INTENSITY2", ] > 10, FALSE) : 
  undefined columns selected`

Comment: That's weird. Your code should produce such an error. Does `tf4["INTENSITY2", ] > 10` produce a logical vector?

Allright, there is another solution: `dplyr::select_if(tf4, tf4["INTENSITY2", ] > 10)`.

Comment: Thanks, I would rather stick to simple ideas as my skills are elementary. Transposing the matrix is one great idea that I got here from the discussion and then working on columns is easy.

Comment: Yes! Using tidy data is much easier. I'll provide another snippet of code, so you may choose =)
`library(tidyverse);
tf4 %>% 
  rownames_to_column("tmp") %>% 
  gather(variable, val, -tmp) %>% 
  spread(tmp, val)
`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works as well.

```
tf4[,unname(apply(tf4['INTENSITY2',],1,function(x) which(x>10)))]
```

Comment: apply returns the names of the columns. unname removes them. 1 signifies that we are applying the function rowwise, and not columnwise (which is 2).

Comment: though I have understood and found it exactly suitable, I wonder why working with rows is so difficult than working with columns.

Comment: variables as columns and observations as rows is the standardized way to set up a dataframe. most work is done to improve these operations. However, in this operation, we are treating the rows (sd, mean, etc.) as the variable, and the columns (materials) as observations, which is not an ideal setup.