# Filtering rows of a dataframe by column values

Tags: r

I have a dataframe with 10 columns. One column gives bird species' names. There's actually 300 species but I'm just interested in 200 of them. I would like to keep only the information about this 200 species.

Screenshot of my table: https://i.stack.imgur.com/OcJyI.png

I can't just write : `filter(Species == "Mallard" & Species == "Wood-pigeon")`

I have a matrix with all the 200 selected species. But, I don't know how to use this matrix to select to relevant rows in my dataframe. Is it possible with subset/filter/etc function to select rows based on a matrix?

What are the correct codes please ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Filter data.frame rows by a logical condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1686569/filter-data-frame-rows-by-a-logical-condition)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `==` with `&` is not going to work anyway as we don't find the different 'Species' in the same cell.  With that code, it would be `|` instead of `&`.  But, this can be done more easily with `%in%` on a vector of values e.g.

```
subset(df1, Species %in% c("Mallard", "Wood-pigeon"))
```

the

```
c("Mallard", "Wood-pigeon")
```

can be extended to any number of Species