# How to sort a dataset?

Tags: r

My assignment is
sorting "Petal.Length" in iris dataset (which is offered by R)

'L' (less than 1.6)

'M' (between L and H)

'H" (more than 5.1)

and print out? display? the outcome

sorry for my broken english

Thank you in advance

Comment: Or this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1686569/filter-data-frame-rows-by-a-logical-condition

Answer (score 0):

with `subset` you can filter the dataframe based on each of your 3 conditions. Then, `rbind` those together:

```r
rbind(
  subset(iris, Petal.Length < 1.6),
  subset(iris, Petal.Length>=1.6 & Petal.Length<=5.1),
  subset(iris, Petal.Length > 5.1)
)
```