# Select data frame value based on specific row and column in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I'm struggling with this question
Say I'm given a data frame consisting of this data.

```
Country | Year | GDP (Million)|
Australia, 2000, 50
Australia, 2001, 100
USA, 2000, 120
Canada, 2001, 50
```

There are thousands of columns and they are constantly changing so  `df[2,3]` isn't an option.
How would I

1. Select Australias GDP for just the year 2000
2. Find the Average of Australian GDP for the dataset.
   Thanks for your help

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Calculate the mean by group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11562656/calculate-the-mean-by-group)

Comment: This answers part one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1686569/filter-data-frame-rows-by-a-logical-condition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df
    Country Year GDP
1 Australia 2000  50
2 Australia 2001 100
3       USA 2000 120
4    Canada 2001  50
df$GDP[df$Country == 'Australia' & df$Year == 2000] # GDP of Australia in 2000
[1] 50
mean(df$GDP[df$Country == 'Australia']) # GDP of Australia
[1] 75
```

Comment: How would I find the average GDP for every country in the data frame and input that into its own data frame?

Comment: Try `aggregate(GDP ~ Country, df, mean)` or using `dplyr` package: `df %>% group_by(Country) %>% summarise(AVG_GDP = mean(GDP))`

Comment: Thank you my friend!

Answer (score 2):

Above mentioned solution by Karthik is perfectly fine. However, if you are more inclined towards using pipe operator `%>%`, you can have a look at the following:

```r
# get all the values in the data frame.
df <- data.frame(Country = c("Australia", "Australia", "USA", "Canada"),
                 Year = c("2000", "2001", "2000", "2001"),
                 GDP = c(50, 100, 120, 150))

# to calculate Australia GDP for year 2000
df %>% 
  filter(df$Country == "Australia" & df$Year == "2000") %>% 
  pull(GDP)


# mean of Australia GDP
df %>% 
  filter(df$Country == "Australia") %>% 
  summarise(Australia_GDP_mean = mean(GDP))
```