# Comparing two visits in R

Tags: r, longitudinal

I have a data with three variables. Patient ID as ID, Visit as Visit, and a third variable as Var. I have two visits and I would like to subset the IDs:

1. IDs that have missing value of Var in the Visit 2
2. IDs had a value 2 for Var in the Visit 1 but 1 in the Visit 2 and vice versa

```
ID Visit Var
1    1   2
1    2   2
2    1   1
2    2   2
3    1   2
3    2   1
4    1   2
4    2   NA
```

Comment: What have you tried already, which part are you stuck at?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Filter data.frame rows by a logical condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1686569/filter-data-frame-rows-by-a-logical-condition)

Comment: Can you show your expected output ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can subset using `[` and using `==` for equal, `&` for and, `is.na` to test for missing values.

```
unique(x$ID[x$Visit == 2 & is.na(x$Var)])
#[1] 4

intersect(unique(x$ID[!is.na(x$Var) & x$Var == 2 & x$Visit==1])
        , unique(x$ID[!is.na(x$Var) & x$Var == 1 & x$Visit==2]))
#[1] 3
```

Data:

```
x <- read.table(header=TRUE, text="ID Visit Var
1    1   2
1    2   2
2    1   1
2    2   2
3    1   2
3    2   1
4    1   2
4    2   NA")
```